# Jekyll removing / in paths

Tags: markdown, jekyll, redcarpet

I am trying to create a complex table in Jekyll and rather than use the Redcarpet table syntax I am just using plain old HTML.

The table contains images which, when rendered on the page, look fine, but when I build the site either Jekyll or Redcarpet is omitting the "/" and so breaks the link?

Thanks!

On page

```
<img src"img/table-images/bardebts-01.png">
```

After compile

```
<img src"img table-images bardebts-01.png>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `=` in your `img` tag. Try this:

```
<img src="img/table-images/bardebts-01.png">
```

Or in markdown

```
![bar debts](img/table-images/bardebts-01.png)
```